# numpy.distutils missing from numpy installation, theano tries to use it

Tags: python, numpy, docker, theano

I am trying to build a Docker image with Theano and Lasagne. These are the main steps:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:8.0-cudnn5-devel
RUN apt-get install -y libopenblas-dev python-dev python-pip
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install nose numpy scipy pandas h5py scikit-image scikit-learn jupyter
RUN pip freeze > requirements.txt && pip install -r requirements.txt --upgrade && rm requirements.txt
RUN pip install --upgrade https://github.com/Theano/Theano/archive/master.zip
RUN pip install --upgrade https://github.com/Lasagne/Lasagne/archive/master.zip
```

When the image is ready I start it up and try to test theano by simply importing theano in ipython. I get the following error (end of it):

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gof/cmodule.pyc in std_include_dirs()
   1579
   1580 def std_include_dirs():
-> 1581     numpy_inc_dirs = np.distutils.misc_util.get_numpy_include_dirs()
   1582     py_inc = distutils.sysconfig.get_python_inc()
   1583     py_plat_spec_inc = distutils.sysconfig.get_python_inc(plat_specific=True)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'distutils'
```

The installed versions according to pip are: numpy (1.12.0) and Theano (0.9.0b1). I have another image that works for some reason. `numpy.distutils` is not present there either but Theano does not try to call it on `import theano` command.

1. Why isn't `numpy.distutils` installed with `numpy`?
2. Why does Theano try to use it?
3. Most importantly: how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Installing `https://github.com/Theano/Theano/archive/master.zip` gives you the beta release of the library, and it doesn't seem to work properly for every system.

Unless you absolutely need some feature from `Theano 0.9`, I would suggest that you install from pip's own repositories instead. Probably do the same for `Lasagne`.

```
RUN pip install theano lasagne
```